# How can I programmatically determine if an azure webrole instance returns 500 error in onstart method of webrole.cs?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, webrole

I have this scenario: asp.net application running as azure webrole, 2 small instances. Sometimes when the vm's are restarting, one of my instances returns 500 error, I have to manually restart each instance and hope for the best. How can I check in the onstart method of the webrole.cs that instance is up and running and if something is wrong to recycle the role ?

Comment: when you have 2 instances only 1 instance will restart/recycle at any given time and azure will manage the availability of your web application. my guess is that there is some issue in the code that causes this error.

Comment: Do you really want to restart the instance just because some HTTP handler failed and returned HTTP 500?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a Band-Aid over the symptom I would recommend solving the root cause.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/19/troubleshooting-scenario-5-internal-server-error-500-in-webrole.aspx for techniques on how to troubleshoot 500 errors in Webroles.

If you really do want to implement this Band-Aid code then you can adapt the code from [Azure Autoscale Restarts Running Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252802/azure-autoscale-restarts-running-instances#comment33803517_22252802) and call RequestRecycle for a 500 response.